# How to print all columns in SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy, I am trying to print out all of the attributes of each model that I have in a manner similar to:

```
SELECT * from table;
```

However, I would like to do something with each models instance information as I get it. So far the best that I've been able to come up with is:

```
for m in session.query(model).all():
    print [getattr(m, x.__str__().split('.')[1]) for x in model.__table__.columns]
    # additional code
```

And this will give me what I'm looking for, but it's a fairly roundabout way of getting it. I was kind of hoping for an attribute along the lines of:

```
m.attributes 
# or 
m.columns.values
```

I feel I'm missing something and there is a much better way of doing this. I'm doing this because I'll be printing everything to .CSV files, and I don't want to have to specify the columns/attributes that I'm interested in, I want everything (there's a lot of columns in a lot of models to be printed).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at SQLAchemy's [metadata reflection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/reflection.html) feature.

> A Table object can be instructed to load information about itself from the corresponding database schema object already existing within the database. This process is called reflection.

Comment: Using flask's sqlalchemy ORM I was able to get the column names via the following: data_table.__table__.columns

Comment: `{i.name: getattr(m, i.name) for i in m.__table__.columns}` this worked fine for me.

Comment: Link seems broken. Can you paste some sample code, how "metadata  reflection" should work? Does this link point at the right inspection, note the `get_columns` function? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/reflection.html#fine-grained-reflection-with-inspector

Answer (score 43):

This is an old post, but I ran into a problem with the actual database column names not matching the mapped attribute names on the instance.  We ended up going with this:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
inst = inspect(model)
attr_names = [c_attr.key for c_attr in inst.mapper.column_attrs]
```

Hope that helps somebody with the same problem!

Comment: Very useful. Thank you!

Comment: Likewise, if you're looking for relationships: `rel_names = [rel.key for rel in inst.mapper.relationships]`. You can also find synonyms and composites: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.attrs

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to access the attribute names from the `column` object. As it stands I have to access both in the same comprehension: `unique_columns = [c_attr.key for c_attr in inst.column_attrs if inst.columns[c_attr.key].unique]`

Answer (score 32):

Probably the shortest solution (see the recent [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#accessing-tables-and-columns)):

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect
columns = [column.name for column in inspect(model).c]
```

The last line might look more readable, if rewrite it in three lines:

```
table = inspect(model)
for column in table.c:
    print column.name
```

Comment: nice solution, this fixed my problem

Comment: This also works with flask-sqlalchemy set up

Answer (score 26):

Building on Rodney L's answer:

```
model = MYMODEL
columns = [m.key for m in model.__table__.columns]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
print repr(model.__table__)
```

Or just the columns:

```
print str(list(model.__table__.columns))
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is the easiest way:

```
print [cname for cname in m.__dict__.keys()]
```

EDIT: The answer above me using sqlalchemy.inspection.inspect() seems to be a better solution.

Comment: __dict__ not always can help.
I use
    keys = self._sa_instance_state.attrs.items()

Comment: not help..if we have multiple function defined under the model, this will get these function

Answer (score 3):

Put this together and found it helpful:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://testuser:password@localhost:3306/testdb')
DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()
metadata = DeclarativeBase.metadata
metadata.bind = engine


# configure Session class with desired options
Session = sessionmaker()

# associate it with our custom Session class
Session.configure(bind=engine)

# work with the session
session = Session()
```

And then:

```
d = {k: metadata.tables[k].columns.keys() for k in metadata.tables.keys()}
```

Example output `print(d)`:

```
{'orderdetails': ['orderNumber', 'productCode', 'quantityOrdered', 'priceEach', 'orderLineNumber'], 
'offices': ['addressLine1', 'addressLine2', 'city', 'country', 'officeCode', 'phone', 'postalCode', 'state', 'territory'],
'orders': ['comments', 'customerNumber', 'orderDate', 'orderNumber', 'requiredDate', 'shippedDate', 'status'],
'products': ['MSRP', 'buyPrice', 'productCode', 'productDescription', 'productLine', 'productName', 'productScale', 'productVendor', 'quantityInStock'],
'employees': ['employeeNumber', 'lastName', 'firstName', 'extension', 'email', 'officeCode', 'reportsTo', 'jobTitle'], 
'customers': ['addressLine1', 'addressLine2', 'city', 'contactFirstName', 'contactLastName', 'country', 'creditLimit', 'customerName', 'customerNumber', 'phone', 'postalCode', 'salesRepEmployeeNumber', 'state'],
'productlines': ['htmlDescription', 'image', 'productLine', 'textDescription'],
'payments': ['amount', 'checkNumber', 'customerNumber', 'paymentDate']}
```

OR and then:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
cmd = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = :db ORDER BY table_name,ordinal_position"
result = session.execute(
            text(cmd),
            {"db": "classicmodels"}
        )
result.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using SQL Alchemy v 1.0.14 on Python 3.5.2

Assuming you can connect to an engine with create_engine(), I was able to display all columns using the following code.  Replace "my connection string" and "my table name" with the appropriate values.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, select

engine = create_engine('my connection string')

conn = engine.connect()
metadata = MetaData(conn)
t = Table("my table name", metadata, autoload=True)
columns = [m.key for m in t.columns]
columns
```

the last row just displays the column names from the previous statement.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in what I came up with to do this.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper
import collections

# structure returned by get_metadata function.
MetaDataTuple = collections.namedtuple("MetaDataTuple", 
        "coltype, colname, default, m2m, nullable, uselist, collection")


def get_metadata_iterator(class_):
    for prop in class_mapper(class_).iterate_properties:
        name = prop.key
        if name.startswith("_") or name == "id" or name.endswith("_id"):
            continue
        md = _get_column_metadata(prop)
        if md is None:
            continue
        yield md


def get_column_metadata(class_, colname):
    prop = class_mapper(class_).get_property(colname)
    md = _get_column_metadata(prop)
    if md is None:
        raise ValueError("Not a column name: %r." % (colname,))
    return md


def _get_column_metadata(prop):
    name = prop.key
    m2m = False
    default = None
    nullable = None
    uselist = False
    collection = None
    proptype = type(prop)
    if proptype is ColumnProperty:
        coltype = type(prop.columns[0].type).__name__
        try:
            default = prop.columns[0].default
        except AttributeError:
            default = None
        else:
            if default is not None:
                default = default.arg(None)
        nullable = prop.columns[0].nullable
    elif proptype is RelationshipProperty:
        coltype = RelationshipProperty.__name__
        m2m = prop.secondary is not None
        nullable = prop.local_side[0].nullable
        uselist = prop.uselist
        if prop.collection_class is not None:
            collection = type(prop.collection_class()).__name__
        else:
            collection = "list"
    else:
        return None
    return MetaDataTuple(coltype, str(name), default, m2m, nullable, uselist, collection)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this because it's slightly shorter:

```
for m in session.query(*model.__table__.columns).all():
    print m
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have described your `table` as SQLAlchemy [table metadata](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html), then you can use a list comprehension on the columns object [sqlalchemy.schema.Table.c](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.c) to get a list of column names as follows:

```
[col.key for col in table.c]
```