# Strange issue in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider the following code which creates a very simple table (without using SQLAlchemy), then adds an entry to it using SQLAlchemy ORM and retrieves it:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

DB_PATH = '/tmp/tst.db'

#create a DB
sqlite_conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH)
sqlite_conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE tst (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
    c0 INTEGER,
    c1 INTEGER
);''')
sqlite_conn.commit()

#intialize an SA engine/session/mapped class
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///{}'.format(DB_PATH))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

class Tst(Base):
    __table_name__ = 'tst'
    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables[__table_name__]
    columns = list(__table__.columns)
    field_names = [c.name for c in columns]

#add an entry to the table
session = Session()
inst = Tst()
session.add(inst)
session.commit()

#retrieve an entry from the table
session = Session()
inst = session.query(Tst).first()
print inst.c1
```

One may expect that the code above will just print 'None', as 'c1' was not assigned a value. Instead of it, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 39, in <module>
    print inst.c1
AttributeError: 'Tst' object has no attribute 'c1'
```

But if the following line will be removed/commented:

```
    field_names = [c.name for c in columns]
```

the output will be as expected.

**In general, it looks like the iteration over `Table.columns` inside the class definition will cause the last column to be omitted from the class instances.**

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6039787), I actually changed the code to use `Inspector`, and it worked fine. However, AFAIK, accessing `Table.columns` is completely legitimate, so I wanted to understand whether it's buggy behavior or something wrong on my side.

**P.S.** tested with SQLAlchemy 1.1.9

**P.P.S.** the issue doesn't appear to be related to a specific DB dialect - reproduced with MySQL, sqlite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a Python version issue than an SQLAlchemy issue. The root cause is the [leaking of the name `c` from the list-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848082/why-do-list-comprehensions-write-to-the-loop-variable-but-generators-dont) in Python 2. It becomes part of the namespace of the constructed class, and so SQLAlchemy sees it as if you were [explicitly naming the last column in the list `columns` in your class definition](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_columns.html#naming-columns-distinctly-from-attribute-names). Your class definition is equivalent to:

```
class Tst(Base):
    __table_name__ = 'tst'
    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables[__table_name__]
    columns = list(__table__.columns)
    ...
    c = columns[-1]  # The last column of __table__
```

If you change your print statement to:

```
print inst.c
```

you'll get `None` as you expected. If you must have your `field_names`, you could for example remove the name from the namespace:

```
class Tst(Base):
    __table_name__ = 'tst'
    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables[__table_name__]
    columns = list(__table__.columns)
    field_names = [c.name for c in columns]
    del c
```

but this is unportable (and ugly) between Python 2 and 3, since the name would not actually exist in 3. You could also work around the issue with [`attrgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
from operator import attrgetter

class Tst(Base):
    __table_name__ = 'tst'
    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables[__table_name__]
    columns = list(__table__.columns)
    field_names = list(map(attrgetter('name'), columns))
```

or use a generator expression:

```
    field_names = list(c.name for c in columns)
```